# What are these tiny dark red insects?

Tags: entomology, species-identification

I found these creatures stuck to a leaf on my tomato plant in the greenhouse/glasshouse, in early June, in south Oxfordshire in the United Kingdom.

They are each about 1-2mm in size. They didn't move much, even when gently nudged, although some did crawl tentatively.

I would be very interested to know what these are, especially if they are a beneficial species or a pest!

[image: Tiny dark red insects]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These little creatures look a lot like White-margined Burrowing Bug or *Sehirus cinctus* nymphs.

[image: Sehirus cintus nymphs]

Very interesting thing about the *Sehirus cinctus* is their brooding behavior. The female watches the eggs and even feeds the young for a few days. Have a look around. You might see it.

[image]

AFAIK they don't harm your plants.

More info:
http://polyploid.net/bugs/bugs.html 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sehirus_cinctus